# Android - How to get the rotation degrees of an animatorSet

Tags: java, android, rotation, android-animation

I have a space ship `ImageView` that I'm rotating with the help of the following `AnimatorSet`:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:ordering="sequentially" >

<objectAnimator
    android:duration="5000"
    android:propertyName="rotation"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:valueTo="-360"
    android:valueType="floatType" 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" />
```

In order to start and end the animation I'm using this `OnTouchListener`:

```
turnShipLeft_btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            if (arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                spaceShip_setLeft.start();
            } else if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                spaceShip_setLeft.cancel();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Once `spaceShip_setLeft.cancel();` is executed, I want to do 2 things:

1. Store the exact rotation degree where it was stopped in a local variable.
2. Set my rotation degree variable on the next `AnimatorSet`'s `android:valueFrom=""` so it will start the animation from the exact position where `spaceShip_setLeft` animation ended.

I'm breaking my head over this for too long now. Any help will be very much appreciated!

PS. If you can include you'r own code snippets, it would be totally awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use XML if you want to use dynamic values.

For simplicity, I wrote my own little demo inside of the default Android Application Project (the newest one that has the fragment). You should be able to adapt to your code as necessary.

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    Button btn_A;
    Button btn_B;
    TextView hello;
    ObjectAnimator mAnimation;
    AnimatorSet transSet;
    Float valuefrom=0f;
    Float valueto=-360f;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        btn_A= (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn_B= (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        hello= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        btn_A.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {         
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                if(!transSet.isRunning()){
                    transSet.start();
                }
            }
        });

        btn_B.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {         
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Float save = (Float) mAnimation.getAnimatedValue();
                Log.d("TAG", "Value" +save);
                valuefrom= save;
                valueto= save-360;
                transSet.cancel();
                //re-init the animation
                doObjectAnimator();
            }
        });

        //init the animation
        doObjectAnimator();
        return rootView;
    }

    public void doObjectAnimator(){
        mAnimation= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(hello, "rotation", valuefrom, valueto);
        mAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        mAnimation.setDuration(5000);
        mAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        //define your other animations here and add them to the set like: set.play(anim1).before(anim2);
        transSet= new AnimatorSet();
        transSet.play(mAnimation);

    }
}
```